# Traceroute showing inter-vlan routing?

Tags: routing, vlan, traceroute

I currently have two different devices (one server and one client device) that are on separate VLANs (VLAN 5 and VLAN 10 respectively). When the client device runs a tracert to the server, the tracert is able to complete as such.

```
C:\>tracert 192.168.32.200

Tracing route to 192.168.32.200 [192.168.32.200]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

 1     6 ms   <1 ms   <1ms  192.168.30.150
 2    <1 ms   <1 ms   <1ms  192.168.32.200 [192.168.32.200]

Trace complete.

C:\>
```

My understanding is that a layer 3 router is required to route traffic between VLANs, which we have connected to the layer 3 switch. Is this correct? Why am I not able to see the Layer 3 router's IP within the tracert output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Layer 3 device is required. It could be Layer 3 Switch as well. No separate router is required. According to your explanation Intervlan routing has been configured. If you have Layer 3 switch, SVI is required to communicate between vlans. According to your Explanation

`192.168.30.150` will be SVI(Switch Virtual Interface) or Gateway of your current VLAN.

Answer (score 2):

You are. The first line is the interface of the router.

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify. 192.168.30.150 is the IP address of the interface VLAN that the client is sitting on.

Comment: Yes, the vlan interface is the layer 3 switch which does the routing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually information provided is not clear not not enough to provide your the answer . Still clarification to your questions with possible examples scenario..

**Example 1**

If VLAN 5 and VLAN 10 are configured in router inter -VLAN routing   than traffic will reach router interfàce to pass the traffic between different subnets or different VLANS .

`Traceroute output will be`

1 ) Client default gateway ip (VLAN 5)

2 )  VLAN 10 gateway ip address

3 )  Actually server ip address .

**Traffic flow scenario will be same if SVI are configured in layer3 switch instead of in router**